# How to recover wordpress website moved from a PC to another

Tags: migration

I am a beginner at website designing. I have just switched laptops so I removed everything from my old laptop and transferred it to a new one through a 1 TB drive. In that went my xampp, and consequently, the wordpress folder.

I was working on a wordpress website through local host. It's all done. I just need to upload it to Cpanel (I dont know how yet. Watching youtube videos and moving forward. As I said, a complete beiginner)

I tried opening the website on new laptop. Research said I had to import phpmyadmin from the old laptop. Now I cant open the website on either laptops and am stuck. I will really appreciate suggestions. I need to get this website live asap.

Comment: How did you copy the database between laptops? Presumably you have a MySQL instance running on the old laptop: have you exported the database from that? You'll need that both for the new development laptop and the uploaded site. If you have the mysql database files you might be able to attach them to a fresh installation of the same version of mysql, but a backup and restore would be safer.

Comment: I just simply copied all my 400GB and pasted in a 1TB drive. Copied that entire chunk and pasted on my new laptop. I have no idea how to restore and backup.

Comment: I think I need the phpmyadmin export from the old laptop? I have gone back to it and reinstalled xampp, moved the old wordpress site to htdocs but the website is still not coming up. Hence it's not showing up in phpmyadmin

Comment: If MySQL is still running on the old laptop you can use the command line tools such as mysqldump without needing phpmyadmin. If this is Windows you'll find that in \Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server <version>\bin

Comment: Thank you! Found the bin. Can you please guide me on what to do next?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html I'm not sure if you want all databases or just your WordPress database. You should then be able to import that into phpmyadmin on the new laptop, or if that's not working then there's [instructions for the command line tools here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/reloading-sql-format-dumps.html)